# Best way to block traffic from a domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to block traffice from domain.com.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Hmmm..  Traffic doesn't really come from a domain, it's comes from an IP address.

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean?

Comment: Or is what you are asking is that you would like to block incoming links from a website domain.com?

Comment: I was assuming that OP was looking for an `.htaccess` solution since he tagged it as such. I'm sure he is sitting on a shared hosting account with minimal or no access to firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'll figure you know the IP's you would like to block (you can obtain them from the domain name), so just add something to your `htaccess` like the following:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
deny from 62.89.0.0/19
deny from 77.95.184.0/21
deny from 80.86.224.0/20
#
# more here if you wanted
#
allow from all
</LIMIT>
```

---

If you need to find the IP of a domain you can [just use this simple tool](http://domaintoip.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server configuration, set up an iptables rule. If you don't, use a .htaccess-file. Example for blocking an IP range (136.129.4.0-136.129.4.255) using iptables until the next reboot (you have to do this as root)(to make it permanent, you have to put it in an initscript):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 136.129.4.0/8 -j DROP
```

For a htaccess example, see Urdas post - but htaccess just forbids http access, iptables completely discards all incoming traffic from the selected IPs.

Answer (score 0):

@thejh your method is correct but your allocating more memory than you should be, this can be used against you in the case of a DoS

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -s $IP -j DROP
```